# hey can you tell me how does the output comes in the following code?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am a bit confused about how this code works can you help. I am trying to understand it in deep. So please feel free to refer any links for depth understanding about the subject matter.The output is A B B A

```
    public class RuntimePolymorphism {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A a = new B();
            B b = new B();

            System.out.println(a.c + " " + a.getValue()
                + " " + b.getValue() + " " + b.getSuperValue());
        }
    }
      
    class A {
        char c = 'A';

        char getValue() {
            return c;
        }
    }
      
    class B extends A {
        char c = 'B';

        char getValue() {
            return c;
        }

        char getSuperValue() {
            return super.c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about the output does surprise you?

Comment: Walk through your code line by line and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's an interesting question ;), by the code, from the fist sight, I would say, it should output `A A B A`, yet it producing `A B B A`.

Then, I found a possible typo (or it was intentional, don't know):

```java
A a = new B();
B b = new B();
```

we have two `B`'s here, but we are also doing a type casting at the moment of instantiation of `a` variable. Even if we make `c` field as `public` it still produces the same result.

But, on the other hand, if we'll update to code like this:

```java
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
```

everything will be as expected: `A A B A`.

---

Interesting finding: if we remove overloaded `getValue()` from the `B` class, the output will be
 `A A A A`...

---

**Final conclusion:** we can inherit a non-private field (that's we can access it from derived class), but we can't "overload" it the way we do with methods.

Thus, in Java, polymorphism is only working with methods and not with the fields.

Comment: I think that it is the point of the question, that there is a contrast between the two sides of the `= ` in `A a = new B();` and why it causes the output. Still, I think your answer gets closer to answering the question than the other answer.

Comment: yep, that's the point... moreover, guess what you will have if you'll do `System.out.println(((A)b).c);` :) @Yunnosch

Comment: it seems like it fetches the field statically `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Yunnosch, now I get confused with my new finding :P, try to run the code with removed `getValue()` method from the `B` class... 0_o

Answer (score 0):

The instance variable **C** from **A** is simply hidden in **B**
– A.C is ‘**A**’ because it's set in the class **A**
– A.getValue() returns ‘**B**’ because the object is of type **B**

Comment: "a.c is ‘A’ because it's set in the class A" does not really satisfy me, because in `A a = new B();` the value of a.c could be caused by the part `A a` or by the part `new(B)`. Seeing that the result of `a.getValue()` is obviously caused by the `new(B)` part, I do not see why the result of `a.c` should be caused by the `A a` part.

Answer (score 0):

So I think we should first understand the difference between **Hiding** and **Polymorphism**.

When you declare a subclass with a variable name the same as the superclass variable, then the subclass variable just **hides** the superclass variable.

For Runtime **Polymorphism**, a subclass method would need to override a superclass method. When a method in a subclass has the signature ( name and parameters ) and same return type as a method in its superclass, then the method in the subclass overrides the method in the superclass.

Another important point is that **Polymorphismm** ( Runtime in this case ) acts on methods that are evaluated at run time. But the initialization of values to the variables happens at compile time.

1. So, when  `A a = new B();` is executed, `a`'s instance variable `c` has the value `'A'`. So even if the reference `a` is pointing to a `B` object, the instance variables it refers to would be that of `A`.

Hence the output when we run `a.c` would be `A`.

2. But since the method `getValue()` is overriden in the subclass, a would call the overriden method ( because it is pointing to the subclass `B` object ).

Hence the output when we run `a.getValue()` would be `B`

So, when  `B b = new B();` is executed, `b`'s instance variable `c` has the value `'B'`. And this **hides** the variable `c` of the superclass. And if we want to refer to the immediate superclass's instance variables then we access it via `super.<variable_name>` So even if the reference `a` is pointing to a `B` object, the instance variables it refers to would be that of `A`.

3. The reference `b` is pointing to an object of type `B` and hence it would call `B`'s getValue() method.

Hence the output when we run `b.getValue()` would be `B`.

4. As discussed above, we access the immediate superclass's instance variables via `super.<variable_name>`

Hence the output when we run `b.getSuperValue()` would be `A`